# Add class if data length > 0

Tags: javascript

How can I add a class for `data.players.length` if its value is > 0

```
tracker_players.appendChild(wrap_span( + data.players.length + '/' + data.info.sv_maxclients, 'tracker_svplayers'))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about...

`data.players.length > 0 && tracker_players.appendChild(wrap_span( + data.players.length + '/' + data.info.sv_maxclients, 'tracker_svplayers'))`

Comment: It doesn't add class for data.players.length

Comment: Code Updated!  Will only append child if `data.players.length > 0`